# Error in open AppRestrictionEnforcer project in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-import

While importing sample project in android studio, this error coming as Access is denied

[image: Error while open project]

even if i click on : Fix Gradle wrapper and re-import project [image]

You can find this project in this directory of your PC : 
~\SDK\samples\android-23\admin\AppRestrictionEnforcer

Comment: this could be a permission restriction. Try using your Administrator account.

Comment: from where i can change administrator account in studio ? and if u talking about window's admin account then i'm already login in that.

Comment: If anyone wanna try their own. you can find this project in this path in ur PC : `~\SDK\samples\android-23\admin\AppRestrictionEnforcer`

Comment: Start Android Studio as Administrator by right clicking it

Comment: @cricket_007 tnx for suggestion. I done it too but still error come same. I think the file gradle-wrapper.property is making some restriction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it. thnx for all of u. I edit the following files as :

build.gradle (application) as :

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    }
```

gradle-wrapper.properties as:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

Comment: 2.12 is latest version of Gradle, by the way